# XML to/from Java/Kotlin, cross-platform

Tags: javascript, java, xml, xsd, kotlin

I have an XML format specified with XSD and I want to generate the corresponding Java (or Kotlin) sources including (de)serialization. I know JAXB, but as far as I understand, it heavily relies on reflection. This is no option for me, because I want the generated sources to be ready for transpilation to JavaScript (by GWT or Kotlin/JavaScript for example). Because of this, these are the requirements:

1. Using an XSD schema, generate the corresponding Java or Kotlin source code
2. Do not use reflection, but plain old Java classes which include serialize/deserialize methods
3. Inject an XML IO interface (like StaX) with the required methods (which I can instatiate depending on the target: JVM, JavaScript, Android, ...)

Do you know a tool for this task or do I have to create my own solution?

Comment: If you want to have a (de)serializer which works in both Java and JS it must be written in Kotlin entirely as Kotlin can't translate Java to JS. You could though have a interface and different implementations for Java and JS. In that case you could use Java and JS code (but only in the appropriate parts)

Comment: Kotlin is an option, but also Java sources transpiled with GWT

Comment: "I know JAXB, but as far as I understand, it heavily relies on reflection.". The generated sources do not rely on reflection!

Comment: I believe you are right, but the sources generated by JAXB (xjc) contain annotations for the classes and fields, and how can they be processed if not using reflection?